# 404 Error with Durandal Starter Kit and Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, durandal

I have just installed the [Durandal Starter Kit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Durandal.StarterKit/) via Nuget and was hoping to start building Durandal apps using Visual Studio and the MVC framework. I've read a couple of articles and blog posts like [this](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/02/08/using-durandal-to-create-single-page-apps) but whenever I try and set up a sample Durandal application I get a 404 error with the browser complaining: '`The resource can't be found.`'

I've checked and the Nuget installation has set up `DurandalController.cs` and deleted the default MVC controller. The project was created as an 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application' using the 'Empty' template. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the installation of the Durandal Starter Kit had created a new default controller but hadn't set it as the default route for the project.

To fix it, I navigated to `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` and in `RegisterRoutes()` I changed the default routes.MapRoutefrom:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

to:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Durandal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The application worked straight away after this change.